# Get largest (size in bytes) row from mysql database with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm using a tool to manipulate a database that has 650 tables. Its failing with a SQL `max_allowed_packet` size error, but not telling me which table or row is causing the problem.

I know that I can fix this by changing the `max_pocket_size` directive, but I'd like to know where the problem data is and how much space its taking up. Is there any way to search across the entire database to find rows which are taking up the most space?

=======================================

More information to answer the comments.

I'm trying to do a Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration using Magento's data migration tool. I know that some images have been saved to the database instead of the file system and I strongly suspect that its these records in the database which are causing it to try and move too much data in one go.

Comment: Why you decide that the entity which oversized `max_allowed_packet` value is ONE record? and even is a record?

Comment: This the 'gone away' error? This doesn't mean that there is problem data. Why do you think there's a problem? What manipulation are you doing?

Comment: If the data that you suspect is a text or character based column, why not use a SELECT query to show for the index key value and that column's length, then you can 'edit' it before trying your migration?  You could instead do a text, not binary, export of the table and then look at the table values in a text editor.